# I'm try to insert all data of datagridview in access DB, But it showing an error 'Column named Challan No cannot be found. Parameter name: columnName'

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Private Sub Button_IWP_Save_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_IWP_Save.Click
    DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

        Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\SUKHVIR PC\Documents\InwardDB.accdb")

            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into inwarddb values( @challan No,@date,@Company,@Item Name,@qty,@Unit)", conn)


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@challan No", row.Cells("Challan No").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", row.Cells("Date").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comapny", row.Cells("Company").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item Name", row.Cells("Item Name").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", row.Cells("QTY").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit", row.Cells("Unit").Value)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

    Next

    MsgBox("Save Successful", vbOK)
End Sub
```

[image]

I'm trying to insert all data of datagridview in access DB, But it showing an error

> Column named Challan No cannot be found. Parameter name: columnName

Comment: Study your table. "challan no" is either misspelled (like "comapny") or isn't there.

Comment: If you were writing a method in VB, would you expect it to be OK to put spaces in the parameter names? I would hope not. In that case, why do you think SQL would allow spaces in parameter names?

Comment: While it is allowed to omit the column list in an INSERT statement when inserting to all columns, it is considered bad practice to do so because it is easier to make a mistake. You should specify the columns that you're inserting to.

Comment: You are probably assuming that the header text of a grid column is the identifier. It isn't. They may contain the same text but they are not the same value. If you haven't given each column a name then you can't retrieve them by name. Either name the columns or retrieve them by index.

Comment: Why are you retrieving data from the grid in the first place? Bind a DataTable to the grid and then save that to the database using a data adapter with a single call to Update.

Comment: @Gustav, I think you'll find that the error message is referring to a grid column, not a table column.